# Extent Report Framework -How to get the Values Stored in Extent report Log Function

Tags: java, report, extentreports

We use Extent report in my project. I want to access the values stored during runtime. For example in the catch block of the test case, I have a line `Log(Failure,"faiure comments")`.

In the finally block, I am trying to create a function where, if the testcase fails, I will need to use the value of the log function and store it for some purpose.

Is it possible? I am using java with selenium in POM framework.

Comment: People will probably need more information than this.  Is `Failure` a `Throwable`?  Is it just a `String`, etc.?  What `Log` method is this (what class does it come from, etc.)?  You could use `ThreadLocal`s (and a wide array of other things) to accomplish this task, but you might need to subclass/modify wherever your `Log` method comes from.  Or you could add some form of aspects which handled this for you; but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Hi , the log method that i am refering to is  logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"String Message to Log for Each Step in Test Case"); which is part of the Extendreport Jar

Comment: We could really do with seeing your current code, it will help us identify exactly what needs to change.

Comment: I will post the code once I am in in the office .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 4, you can do:

```
extent.getStats()
```

To drill into each data point for the entire run session.  To drill into a single data-point, for example, the current test's last log:

```
test.getModel().getLogContext().getLast().getStatus()
```

But I would rather recommend you to use a test framework such as TestNG or Junit and listen to the context provided by these instead. Using Extent to do the same would work, but I would think its more intuitive and productive using your test framework.

PS. It is Extent, not Extend.

Comment: Thank you so much .I will try this out today

Comment: hi checked with my  Extent version it's only 2.41.1 . Is there any other similar method that I could use?

Comment: We also use log4j  version 2.8.2 . Can we achieve this with log4j?

Comment: Would recommend upgrading to version 4 infact. Version 2 is no longer get supported. Log4j, you cannot do that. Use TestNg or Junit instead for this.